# Is it still a ramified ideal when the generating prime number seems to split?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

For example, in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{34}]$, it is clear that $\langle 2 \rangle = \langle 2, \sqrt{34} \rangle^2$ and $\langle 17 \rangle = \langle 17, \sqrt{34} \rangle^2$.

However, looking at the numbers rather than the ideals generated by them, I see that $2 = (6 - \sqrt{34})(6 + \sqrt{34})$ and $17 = (-1)(17 - 3 \sqrt{34})(17 + 3 \sqrt{34})$.

It seems clear to me from this that $\langle 2 \rangle = \langle 6 + \sqrt{34} \rangle^2$, since $6 - \sqrt{34} \in \langle 6 + \sqrt{34} \rangle$ by way of the unit $35 + 6 \sqrt{34}$ and thus $\langle 6 - \sqrt{34} \rangle = \langle 6 + \sqrt{34} \rangle$.

However, I'm not seeing how to prove that $17 - 3 \sqrt{34} \in \langle 17 + 3 \sqrt{34} \rangle$, and I'm also beginning to wonder if I'm even on the right track with this line of thought.

Comment: $$\frac{17-3\sqrt{34}}{17+3\sqrt{34}} = \frac{(17 - 3\sqrt{34})^2}{-17} = -\frac{17\cdot 35 - 17\cdot 6\sqrt{34}}{17} = -35 + 6\sqrt{34}$$

Comment: Huh, it's the same unit as with the other one. I made a mistake with my calculations for $17$ somewhere...

Comment: $(17-3\sqrt{34})(17+3\sqrt{34})=-17$ (not $17$) if that matters...

Comment: @coffeemath I think it does matter, even though both are absorbed into the ideal. I'll make a change, and if Mr. Brooks does not approve, he can amend it differently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's still a ramified ideal. But first, let's look at a prime number that really does split in this domain: $$(519 - 89 \sqrt{34})(519 + 89 \sqrt{34}) = 47.$$ Now try $$\frac{519 - 89 \sqrt{34}}{519 + 89 \sqrt{34}} = \frac{538675 - 92382 \sqrt{34}}{47}$$ and $$\frac{519 + 89 \sqrt{34}}{519 - 89 \sqrt{34}} = \frac{538675 + 92382 \sqrt{34}}{47}.$$ This tells us that neither factor of 47 is a divisor of the other.

By contrast, you have already observed that $$\frac{6 - \sqrt{34}}{6 + \sqrt{34}} = 35 - 6 \sqrt{34}$$ (which is a unit) and $$\frac{6 + \sqrt{34}}{6 - \sqrt{34}} = 35 + 6 \sqrt{34}$$ (which is also a unit). Daniel Fisher has done similar calculations for 17 in the comments.

Therefore $\langle 2 \rangle = \langle 6 + \sqrt{34} \rangle^2$ (as you've already noted) and $\langle 17 \rangle = \langle 17 + 3 \sqrt{34} \rangle^2$. The ideals ramify even though the generating numbers *look* like they split.

It's a similar situation with 5 and 11 in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{55}]$. We can generalize: if $p \mid d$ and $p = (a - b \sqrt d)(a + b \sqrt d)$, then there is a unit $u$ such that $u(a - b \sqrt d) = a + b \sqrt d$ and vice-versa, and therefore $\langle p \rangle = \langle a + b \sqrt d \rangle^2$.